# python bokeh FileInput text

Tags: python, html, bokeh

The default text on the bokeh [FileInput](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.inputs.html) is "Choose File".

Is there a way i can change this text, e.g. to "Upload image"?

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import FileInput

def upload_fit_data(attr, old, new):
    print("fit data upload succeeded")
    print(file_input.value)
file_input = FileInput(accept=".jpg")
file_input.on_change('value', upload_fit_data)

doc=curdoc()
doc.add_root(file_input)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Bokeh 1.4 this is not configurable. Seem like a reasonable ask (and also would be a good task for a new contributor) so I'd encourage you to [make a new issue about it](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues).